# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_images__id() on null

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin and when I use search on my website I get a fatal error in this line specifically: `$listing->get_images__id();`:

```php
function redirect_listing_view_page() {
    the_post();

    $listing = Models\Listing::query()->get_by_id( get_post() );

    $listing->get_images__id();

    $vendor = $listing->get_vendor();

    hivepress()->request->set_context( 'listing', $listing );
    /hivepress()->request->set_context( 'vendor', $vendor );

    return false;
}
```

Is there a way to modify the code to get around this error?

Note: The full error code is on my website:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_images__id() on null
> in /path/to/public_html/wp-content/plugins/hivepress/includes/controllers/class-listing.php on line 664

Call stack:

> HivePress\Controllers\Listing::redirect_listing_view_page()
> call_user_func()
> wp-content/plugins/hivepress/includes/components/class-router.php:642
>
> HivePress\Components\Router::set_page_template()
> wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324
>
> WP_Hook::apply_filters()
> wp-includes/plugin.php:205
>
> apply_filters() wp-includes/template-loader.php:104
> require_once() wp-blog-header.php:19
>
> require() index.php:17

I tried to make several changes to the code and did not succeed. I tried to create function code to bypass this but it did not work.

I don't know what's going wrong and it's only in the search box on my site that this error occurs.

The problem could be a conflict between two plugins on WordPress, but I cannot do without any basic plugin on my site. I want any modification, even if it is temporary.

Comment: From the function code it doesn't look like the plugin is meant to be used outside posts / pages (or at least this particular function isn't). If you haven't done so already, try reaching out to the support team of the HivePress plugin and report the issue to them, they should be able to help you figure out what's wrong: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/hivepress/